# Border Radius on Firefox 41.0.2

Tags: html, css

Any ideas why my border radius doesn't work in Firefox version 41.0.2?

http://jsfiddle.net/967z3kgg/

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid $blue;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left:0;
  margin-bottom:100px;
  background:green
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is invalid property. You are supposed to use `-` only before proprietary properties like `-moz` or `-webkit` so <s>`-border-radius: 10px;`</s> is invalid

It should be `border-radius: 10px;`

Also, a side note for you, you don't have to use browser prefix anymore as `border-radius` has a decent browser support. You can check the browser support for the same on [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius).

Comment: Ha ha ha. You answered 13 second faster than me.

Comment: I had to hover over the 'answered 1 min ago' - wow, you're both amazing!!